# Does MPMoviePlayerController can play ts stream on ios?

Tags: ios5, avfoundation, http-live-streaming

This is my code:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:8080/m3u8/test.ts"]];
```

It can not work, and I segment it by m3u8-segmenter to test.m3u8, it can play.

I want to know , How to play ts stream on ios?

Comment: why do you want to run .ts file instead of .m3u8 file because .m3u8 has link of ts and use for live streaming.

Comment: I do not need live stream. so playing ts is simple for me

Comment: have you added this  

AddType application/x-mpegURL m3u8
AddType video/MP2T ts

to apache2/http.config